# How long does it take for an AdMob Ad unit ID to become active?

Tags: android, admob

I created a new Ad unit ID around 4 hours ago and started using it in the release build of my unreleased Android app. But all I get is a blank view and the following logcat output:

```
W/Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 400
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Since the the Ad unit IDs for the other apps in the same AdMob account work - even when used in the app in question - the best explanation I can come up with is that the new ID hasn't been activated or properly propagated yet.

How long does this usually take or what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the exact time it took but 12 hours after creating the new Ad unit ID it was active.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the Ad Unit ID starts delivering ads immediately, and sometimes the Ad Unit ID can take a few hours before delivering ads. There is no official AdMob documentation stating the activation time.