# Admob unitid not workigng with reactnative but test unit id does work?

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-native, admob, react-redux

## I am facing a weired situation where i have implemented a googleadmob in react native app.

```
<AdMobBanner
          bannerSize="fullBanner"
          adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
          testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
          didFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} />
where ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 is the test id provided by googleadmob
```

but when i created new Adunit ID and replaced test id with the newly created ad unit id i am unable to any ads Why ??
Note : i am working on dev environment i guess it won't affect but still ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove testDeviceID="EMULATOR" when you run on real device.

Sometimes AdMob may take some times to active the ad unit, please ref to: [How long does it take for an AdMob Ad unit ID to become active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197835/how-long-does-it-take-for-an-admob-ad-unit-id-to-become-active)

One more point, did you input your payment info on AdMob website, AdMob needs your info to serve your ads.